# mobiletype always show network found if netwok is disable

Tags: android

i modify my last code but this code still show network found  i disbale my network but is againshow network show if i disbale network connection is stil show toast other Connection Found  i dont know y  polease help  me

```
final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)       
  getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

 final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile1 = 
                            connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);


    if (mobile1.isAvailable()) {
    Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this," other Connection Found  
",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


public  void onClick(View view) {
String pinemptycheck = pin.getText().toString();
String mobileemptycheck = mobile.getText().toString();
 if  (pinemptycheck.trim().equals("")||(mobileemptycheck.trim().equals("")))
    {


  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Correct Information",   
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


  } 

  else
 {

showProgress();
postLoginData();
 }

    }
        });
}


 else if (!mobile1.isAvailable()) {

Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this,"No other Connection Found ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)

    {

 Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this," No other Connection Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    });
    }}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are disabling mobile connection or wifi connection

Comment: yes  im using simulator and i disbale networkconnection

Comment: in simulator wheni browse any website is not working but in apliccationis also go inside if mbile1.isAvaibale() method i dont know y

Comment: It would be better if you can check your changes on an actual phone

Comment: try the edited answer, change getnetworkinfo to getactivenetworkinfo and change condition as shown below

Comment: yes I have checked, changed and it is working for my emulator

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)       
                  getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

                 final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile1 = 
                                            connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();


                   if (mobile1 != null  && mobile1.isConnected() && mobile1.isAvailable() && (mobile1.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)) {
                Toast.makeText(CheckBoxTest.this," other Connection Found ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
```

Comment: i try this i disbale my network from window  but is still show other network found in simulator tell me why?

Comment: @HayyaAnam did you change getnetworkinfo to getactivenetworkinfo? Also declare connMgr, mobile1 before oncreate in your activity class.

Comment: telll me one this i follow this example also  i disbale my windoe networkconnection when i run this application http://android-solution-sample.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-check-availability-of-network.html  is agains how message network connected i dont know y

Comment: simulator depend on windowXP internet connection or its have anyother wireless mechanism ??

Comment: @HayyaAnam don't disable internet connection on pc, disable it on emulator by pressing F8, try pressing F8 you will see that the 3g icon appears and disappears, when it is disappeared try to run your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :-

Get below permission in your android manifest-

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Have a broadcast receiver with below action in intent filter -

```
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
```

In the onReceive method of the receiver use below code :-

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
            final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
                    .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
                    .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
            if (wifi.isConnected() || mobile.isConnected()) {
                      Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this," other Connection Found  
",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
else
{
Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this,"No other Connection Found ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
        }
```

}

Comment: you can remove the wifi part as per your need

Comment: i do not want wifi i only wnat any other network is avaibale  or not except wifi

Comment: this show error  if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {

Comment: This code should be placed inside the onReceive method of your broadcastreceiver

Comment: i donot use anyonreceive method i use spiner for select network position id position is 3 check otherneteotk